# Pydev / Django not showing in Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse-plugin

After searching and applying the suggested solutions, Pydev is still not showing in Eclipse.
I am using the following version combination and maybe that is where the problem is but I cannot say.

Eclipse 3.8
Java 8
Pydev 5
Kubuntu 16.04

I want to make a start in writing Django for building websites in Python choose for Eclipse as IDE because in the past I also used that IDE for PHP and like to work with it..

Comment: Try downloading Aptana, it is basically Eclipse pre-configured for web development languages including Python and PHP.

Comment: I use LiClipse. It is fantastic.